# Magento : How to convert quote item attribute to order item attribute

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, gomage

I've added a quote item attribute and an order item attribute (and invoice and shipment) called "parent_info":

```
$installer->addAttribute("quote_item", "parent_info", array("type"=>"varchar"));
$installer->addAttribute("order_item", "parent_info", array("type"=>"varchar"));
$installer->addAttribute("invoice_item", "parent_info", array("type"=>"varchar"));
$installer->addAttribute("shipment_item", "parent_info", array("type"=>"varchar"));
```

I was able to save the user input to the quote item, but I can't convert it to the order item.
I've tried to add this code under global in my config file:

```
    <fieldsets>
        <sales_convert_quote_item>
            <parent_info>
                <to_order_item>*</to_order_item>
                <to_invoice_item>*</to_invoice_item>
                <to_shipment_item>*</to_shipment_item>
            </parent_info>
        </sales_convert_quote_item>
    </fieldsets>
```

but when I moved to checkout nothing happened

I've also tried to add an observer:

```
<sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item>
            <observers>
                <extra_options>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>test/observer</class>
                    <method>onSalesConvertQuoteItemToOrderItem</method>
                </extra_options>
            </observers>
        </sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item>
```

But it doesn't get called (I've added a log to the observer method).

What can be the problem? Can it be because I use an extension for the checkout (gomage lightcheckout)?

Comment: Hey Shani, Observer is definitely the right direction to go. Why don't you try disabling the checkout module and see if the observer is being called while it is in default checkout.

Comment: I've tried that but it the observer method still wasn't called. Any Ideas what am I missing?